# Creating Virtual Hosts on ubuntu mint apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am working Linux Mint 17.3 and trying to create virtual hosts on Apache 2.4. I have followed the following procedure, but still can't browse the site:

> 1. Create two new virtual hosts 
>      sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com.conf
> 2. modify each host 
>      sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com.conf 
>      
>        ServerName site1.com 
>        ServerAlias www.site1.com 
>        ServerAdmin admin@site1.com 
>        DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com/public_html 
>        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
>        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
>
> 3.Enable the New Virtual Host Files 
>   sudo a2ensite site1.com
>
> // Disable original html host 
>   sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
>
> sudo service apache2 reload
>
> 4. Add host info 
>      sudo vim /etc/hosts 
>      127.0.0.1:88 site1.com 
>      127.0.0.1:89 site2.com

I have checked out everything online, that I could. Today is my second day.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your second step, you should declare that host as a VirtualHost in the conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName site1.com 
   ServerAlias www.site1.com 
   ServerAdmin admin@site1.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com/public_html
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yes I have done that already. I want to know did I follow the right path or am missing some step in between. Bye the way thanks.